# Getting nearest point distance in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, distance, proximity

How do you calculate the nearest distance from one XY coordinate to another XY.

I'm using Arc Map 10

I went into Arc tool box -> proximity -> then I only have 2 buffering options.

But under buffer I do not see any "near features" option

Comment: near but you need advanced license (arcinfo) http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Near/00080000001q000000/

Comment: GSE uses a focused question/best answer model. Please **edit** your question to contain only one question (other topics can be placed in different questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your other question, you have a Basic license and so don't have access to the Near or Generate Near Table tools. But you can still do it with a [Spatial Join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000). If your XY are just coordinates, you need to make point features out of them first. There are other questions here that cover that.

Spatial Join your points to themselves (if they're in the same layer) with a one-to-one join_operation and closest match_option. Specify a distance field name, and the output table of the join will include a column with the distance (in dataframe CRS units) from each point to its closest neighbor.

Comment: Thanks! Can ArcGIS 10.1 or 10.2.2 calculate near distances?

Comment: Desktop I mean, sorry

Comment: @Kagnew The version isn't really the issue, it's the license level. Certain tools are only available at higher license levels, and Near/GNT happen to be two examples that are only at the highest (Advanced/Info). See http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/about/gis-for-me for more info. However there are often workarounds that can accomplish the same thing at Basic. They just involve more steps or alternative tools. Spatial join is one example of this for doing nearest distances.